# How to render Smoke/Fire in RENDERMAN

Tags: rendering, renderman-render-engine

I am trying out RenderMan 21 but can figure out how to render smoke and fire.

I am assuming I use "PxrVolume" but it puts volume for the whole domain object not the emitter smoke object. I tried attribute nodes (used in cycles) but that doesnt seem to be working for me.

Anyone have any ideas?

I read over the instructions and I can only find stuff for Maya not Blender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out how to render smoke OR fire. (But not both)

You have to type "density" or "flame" in the "Density Float PrimVar".

However this leads me to other questions. (Like how to change the density, and have the flame and smoke render together).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your edit, if renderman has an add shader node, copy the PxrVolume node and set it to flame, and then add both shaders together.

Comment: I wish it were that easy. RenderMan has no add node. It does have a layer node but I tried that and it doesn't seem to work .